# jquery file uploading error

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fileapi

I am using a jquery plugin for uploading contents. This plugin use File api.
when i use chrome there is an error show that

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Object #<File> has no method 'webkitSlice'.
```

here is the error present

```
    /**
 * Return the proper slice (packet)
 * @param {Number} packetId 
 * @returns {Blob} Returns a new Blob object containing the data in the specified range of bytes
 */
function getPacket(packetId){

    var startByte = packetId  * self.packetSize,
    endByte = startByte+self.packetSize,
    packet;

    if ('mozSlice' in self.file) {
        // mozilla
        packet = self.file.mozSlice(startByte, endByte);
    } else {
        // webkit
        packet = self.file.webkitSlice(startByte, endByte); // here
    }
    return packet;
}
```

if any one know about this please help me

Comment: give the code snippet that is related to the line number of this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `webkitSlice` is depracated long time ago and it's not being used anymore for that object. Try `slice()` instead:

```
packet = self.file.slice(startByte, endByte);
```